# PlayFramework 2: Fetch data from h2 database, decimal types not map with Scala decimal type

Tags: scala, anorm

i am new in `PlayFramework` and `Scala`. I am using `PlayFramework` `anorm` for enable database connection and use embedded `h2 database`. When i insert the values into the table, the insertion done successfully. But when i fetch the data from database it generates and error as below:

```
[RuntimeException: Left(TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert 25.50: class java.math.BigDecimal to Float for column ColumnName(USER_DETAIL.AGE,Some(AGE))))]
```

Following is my POJO:

```
case class UserDetail(
 val id: Int,
 val name: String,
 val age: Float
)
```

Following is my controller:

```
def getUserDetail = Action{
val userDetail = UserDetail(13, "James", 25.9F);
var sql: SqlQuery = SQL("SELECT * FROM USER_DETAIL");
def users: List[UserDetail] =  DB.withConnection { implicit connection => 
  sql().map(row => UserDetail(row[Int]("id"), row[String]("name"), row[Float]("age"))).toList
}
println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>: "+users)
Ok(Json.toJson(users));
}
```

Following is my table structure:

```
create table User_Detail(
 id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 name varchar(45),
 age decimal(20, 2)
)
```

I am also trying to replace `decimal` type with `double` in table, but it again generate the same error like above

```
[RuntimeException: Left(TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert 25.50: class java.lang.Double to Float for column ColumnName(USER_DETAIL.AGE,Some(AGE))))
```

Comment: have you tried h2 types Real or Float4 in your table rather than Decimal(20,2) or Double? according to H2 docs, that maps to java.lang.Float, which should convert to scala.Float without issue. see http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#real_type

Comment: @SteveWaldman thanks for your comment. no i am not trying this, but when i will try, i will update the comments.

Comment: Which anorm version are you using? Latest release provides more numeric conversions.

Comment: @cchantep i have latest one.

Comment: Specifically? 2.3.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
case class UserDetail(
 val id: Int,
 val name: String,
 val age: Double
)
```

edit:

And then use `row[Double]("age")` when reading it

Comment: thanks for your answer. This is work for me. But why this is not auto cast to `FLOAT`.

Comment: A conversion from double/numeric to float would raise a loss of precision. Doing it automatically/implicitly would be dangerous.